# Getting logs from AWS CLI in bash with quoted json

Tags: aws-cli, amazon-cloudwatch

aws logs get-log-events --log-group-name $LOGGROUP --log-stream-name $MYLOGSTREAM --region $MYREGION --profile $MYPROFILE --query "events[?contains(message,'Warning')]"

The thing is that "message" contains qouted json

Here is the first part (there are multiple events)

```
[
    {
        "timestamp": 1667560763440,
        "message": "{\"system_id\":\"SYS031\",\"level\":\"Warning\",\"stack_trace\":
```

I would love if the message part was "valid" json, so I could use the --query to filter like "Where system_id = SYS031".

If it can't happen server side in AWS I need a way to convert every message "object" into json client side so I can filter client side.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that I can do it with client side jq like this

aws logs get-log-events --log-group-name $LOGGROUP --log-stream-name $MYLOGSTREAM --region $MYREGION --profile $MYPROFILE --query "events[?contains(message,'Warning')]".message | jq '.[] | fromjson' | jq -r '.message'